# Solving $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(x^2+1)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ with initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x),x\in\mathbb R.$

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Solve $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(x^2+1)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ with initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x),x\in\mathbb R.$

Under which conditions does the solution exists?

Is it unique?

**What I've done:**

The general solution is $u(x,t)=\phi(t-\arctan(x))$.

Applying the initial condition we have $u(x,t)=f(\tan(t-\arctan(x)))$.

Thus the solution exists when $(t-\arctan(x)) \in I,$ where $I=\big(\frac{-(k+1)\pi}{2},\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2}\big),k\in\mathbb N.$

---

Am I correct in the solution ?

How do I check uniqueness?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: @Mattos :) good, how do I check uniqueness? Can I just plot the solutions and to see if they intersect at some point?

Comment: or something more formal is needed?